# Ge Vs Si for AM envelope detector

Tags: amplitude-modulation, vintage

Early solid state radios used Ge diodes as a detector .Si was not available then so this makes sense .Impedances were much lower than the Valve stuff.A 5k Log volume control   pot was common for early solid state where 500K was common for a valve detector .Also the solid state radios had lower output voltages than their valve counterparts . Prebiasing the diode was essential to keep distortion down .When Si transistors arrived I would still often see a Ge detector diode present .Was this because they in the day had lots of glass Ge diodes in the store ? If a Si diode is prebiased it should have low distortion too? Does the more gradual VI curve of the Ge diode give less distortion ? Is the distortion cancellation that prebiasing achieves not as good for Si because there is more distortion to begin with ?

Comment: You mention valves and impedances and I'm not seeing the relevance. Also what is the 5k or 500k resistor you talk about?

Comment: @ Andy aka .If say the impedences and volts are high like say 5V and say 1 meg then diode error due to foward volts is in % terms low so it will sound OK .If you have a DIODE tuner on your stereo amp and are close to the transmitter it will sound great also because your amp might have an input impedence of say 100K . Remember that a diode tuner is a marketing name for a crystal set and there is no power so no diode prebias .The early solid state radio might have audio levels of only 100mV at the envelope detector output .Prebiasing is much more important here .

Comment: Early solid state radios used Germanium for both transistors and detector (50s to early 60s). There were also portable valve radios using the miniature valve sets. Silicon (as a semiconductor) was known about from the from the earliest forms of detector (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat's-whisker_detector ). With any change in technology you always get overlap of materials and techniques - after all we are still using chips designed in the 70s.